# Format a string given in braces

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I have a bit strange need, I'm not sure if this is the way of doing the task but here I go:

In my plotting library (OxyPlot) there is a way of displaying the coordinates of a point above it in the plot. The problem is that around 10 decimals are showed. I don't need that precision and 2 are enough for me. The syntax it uses is:

```
myLine.LabelFormatString = "{0}"; //for showing the X,

myLine.LabelFormatString = "({0}, {1})"; //for showing (X, Y)
```

I don't have access to that {0} directly, therefore I can't format them before. Is there a way of doing someting like:

```
myLine.LabelFormatString = "{0}".ToString(#.##);
```

Or I need to dig in the source code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `f` format specifier to specify the number of decimal places:

```
myLine.LabelFormatString = "{0:f2}";
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that to be so easy! Worked perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use format it like this

```
myLine.LabelFormatString = "{0:0.00}";
```